# How to use protobuf-net for xml-serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, protobuf-net, xmlserializer

Maybe i misunderstood something for serialization. i wanna serialize my .net object fastest way. i made some googling i found protobuf. Myfirstquestion is ProtoBuf.Net has avility for xml serailization.if it has, can i use it for xml serialization.

My model:

```
    [XmlType]
public class CT {
    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
[XmlType]
public class TE {
    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
[XmlType]
public class TD {
    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public List CTs { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    public List TEs { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 4)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 5)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 6)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

my serializer :

```
            CT ct = new CT() { Foo = 1 };
        List<CT> list = new List<CT>();
        list.Add(ct);
        TE te = new TE() { Bar = 2 };
        List<TE> list2 = new List<TE>();
        list2.Add(te);
        TD td = new TD() { Code = "Test",Message = "Yusuf",StartDate = DateTime.Now,EndDate = DateTime.Now,CTs = list,TEs = list2 };
        List<TD> list3 = new List<TD>();
        list3.Add(td);
        Stopwatch stopwatch5 = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch5.Start();

        string str = String.Empty;
             using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) 
        {
            byte[] data =  Serialize(list3);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); <--SHOULD CREATE XML
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
           // str = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(),0,(int)stream.Length); 
        } 
        stopwatch5.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(((double)(stopwatch5.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000000) / 1000000).ToString("0.00 ns"));
        Console.Read();

    }
    public static byte[] Serialize(List<TD> tData) {
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms,tData);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static List<TD> Deserialize(byte[] tData) {
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream(tData)) {
            return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<List<TD>>(ms);
        }
    }
```

it should create xml as a result of "   string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);". But doesn't. How can i produxe xml result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Protocol buffers doesn't serialize objects to XML.**
It produces binary data. And it has its own set of attributes.
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717036/serialize-protocol-buffer-file-into-xml-text-format)

Is Protobuf-net's serialization/deserialization faster than XML ? Yes, [by far](http://www.maxondev.com/serialization-performance-comparison-c-net-formats-frameworks-xmldatacontractserializer-xmlserializer-binaryformatter-json-newtonsoft-servicestack-text/).
However **XmlSerializer is fast enough** for most of the tasks.
What you should remind when using it though, is:

- XmlSerializer instance is generating code on the fly and compile this code into an assembly.
- This generated assembly is then used to serialize and deserialize your objects really fast.
- So you should cache instances of XmlSerializer (and avoid recreating them)
- you could add a warm up by calling Serialize and Deserialize in order to initialize inner objects and jit them.

You could even go further by generating the auto-generated assembly by yourself, but then you should remember to regenerate each time you change the objects (It can be automated with a MsBuild Task).
You can also look further optimizations:

- [On Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238444/performance-optimizing-use-of-generated-xmlserializer-class)
- [With Sgen](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1105/optimized-way-of-xml-serialization-using-sgen-utility)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one tag at the root level of your xml.  So either TD cannot be a list, or you must have an outer tag around the List.  This code works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TD td = new TD()
            {
                Code = "Test",
                Message = "Yusuf",
                StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                EndDate = DateTime.Now,
                CTs = new List<CT>() {
                    new CT() { Foo = 1},
                    new CT() { Foo = 2},
                    new CT() { Foo = 3},
                },
                TEs = new List<TE>() {
                    new TE() { Bar = 1},
                    new TE() { Bar = 2},
                    new TE() { Bar = 3},
                }
            };

           using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) 
            {
                byte[] data =  Serialize(td);
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); 
                doc.LoadXml(xml);
               // str = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(),0,(int)stream.Length); 
            } 

        }
        public static byte[] Serialize(TD tData)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TD));
                serializer.Serialize(ms, tData);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static TD Deserialize(byte[] tData)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(tData))
            {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TD));
                return (TD)xs.Deserialize(ms);
            }
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("CT")]
    public class CT
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Foo", Order = 1)]
        public int Foo { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("TE")]
    public class TE
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Bar", Order = 1)]
        public int Bar { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("TD")]
    public class TD
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CTs",  Order = 1)]
        public List<CT> CTs { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TEs", Order = 2)]
        public List<TE> TEs { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code", Order = 3)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Message", Order = 4)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "StartDate", Order = 5)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "EndDate", Order = 6)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```